# Problem with adding programmatically woocommerce product post into category

Tags: posts, woocommerce-offtopic

I have problem with adding product to category when I creating this product. I have this code:

```
$my_post = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_title' => 'Drukarka '.$_POST['marka'].' '.$_POST['model'],
        'post_content' => $_POST['opis'],
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => $current_user->ID,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'

    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);

wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, get_term_by('slug', 'druk-cyfrowy', 'product_cat'), 'product_cat');
```

Var dump of: `wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, get_term_by('slug', 'druk-cyfrowy', 'product_cat'), 'product_cat');`

Returns this:

```
object(WP_Error)#12822 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(26) "Nieprawidłowa taksonomia." } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

And var dump: of `get_term_by('slug', 'druk-cyfrowy', 'product_cat')`

Returns false and I don't know why.
Please help me

Comment: (wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Druk cyfrowy', 'product_cat' ) this returns invalid taxonomy too

Comment: When I use is_taxonomy() with 'product_cat' argument i have false

Comment: When is this code running?

Comment: It is running from theme function.php when $_POST variables are setted.

Comment: Your code needs to be in a hook. You shouldn't just have raw code running outside a function in `functions.php`. Taxonomies aren't registered until the `init` hook, after `functions.php` is loaded, so you need to hook your code to run after that.